# Which data type in order to reference other documents?

Tags: mongodb, types, mongoid, relation

Although it is not recommended to use MongoDB for N:M relations, you could still use it that way by storing an array of IDs in the document. Therefore models could have a method which queries on the referenced ID and returns an array of objects.

Now the question: Is there a guideline whether to save the "foreign key" (oh how dare I to call it like that!) as a string or as an ObjectId object? I guess the performance will be almost equal because you don't index on them, but maybe they don't need equal space? What would you consider as the better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple math:

MongoDB's ObjectId is a 12-byte binary blob.

The same data in string representation (example: '47cc67093475061e3d95369d') takes 24 bytes. And it also will have to be converted to ObjectId during the query.

The choice is obvious, isn't it?